# How do I make inkscape the default program for .eps files?

Tags: file-association, windows-store-app, inkscape, eps

I installed Inkscape via the Microsoft store.

How do I make Inkscape the default program for .eps files?    Also, how do I add Inkscape onto the list of programs that show under open with?

When I select open with  -> choose another app -> look for an app in Microsoft store   I can search for Inkscape and find it but I don't know what to do next.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So without having to install Inkscape myself, after you hit "look for an app in the Microsoft Store" and you select Inkscape what happens?  You should also select the "always use ..." checkbox before you set the default application.  Have you tried changing the default application for this file extension through Settings?  You should [edit] your question with more detailed information on what step exactly you are stuck on

Comment: Have you installed the application?

Comment: yes although it cannot be opened from microsoft store

Comment: @Ramhound  I cannot select Inkscape see attached images.

Comment: Try the [Windows Desktop](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.1.2/windows/64-bit/exe/dl/) version instead of the Windows Store version